# Double transactions on both a stored procedure and php codes wrapping it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions

my codes are like the below.

1) php codes

```php
\DB::transaction(function () use ($id, $member_id) {

                \DB::select(\DB::raw('call doJob(?,?,@pJobLogId)'), [$id, $member_id]);

});
```

2) the stored procedure, doJob above..

```sql
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RESIGNAL;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    // codes(logic)...

    COMMIT;

END
```

Are there any issues with the above? If I should give up one transaction, which one should I do?

Also I don't know if the double transactions cause this sort of error.
I saw an error log like the below, but this hardly occurs.

> SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when
>   trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MySql official documentation:

> Section 13.3.3 Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit
>
> Transactions cannot be nested. This is a consequence of the implicit
>   commit performed for any current transaction when you issue a START
>   TRANSACTION statement or one of its synonyms.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: And about the second question: I would remove the transaction in the procedure as you are allowed to nest transactions in the application code.